# prepareForSegue Function not returning original switch results after search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

After preforming a search on my tableview and selecting a row, The detailed view controller (MOVdetailViewController) only updates the name and not the information (address, website and other things). Which is located in the MDVC.lodgeNumber that I have setup as a switch. Im now thinking this is not possible due to the detailed information being stored in a switch. All feed back is greatly appreciated

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"lodgedetail"]) {
      MOVDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      MOVDetailViewController * MDVC = [[MOVDetailViewController alloc] init];


      NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      NSString * thelodge = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];

      MDVC = [segue destinationViewController];
      MDVC.lodgeNumber = path.row;
      MDVC.lodgeName = thelodge;



      NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

      if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
          indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
                          indexPathForSelectedRow];
          destViewController.lodgeName = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



      } else {
          indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
          destViewController.lodgeName = [lodgeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        }
      }
   }
```

Example of the switch:

```
  self.title = lodgeName;     
  switch (lodgeNumber) {
      case 0:
          //Abingdon Lodge No. 48
          address.text = @"325 W Main Street Abingdon, Virginia 24210";
          website.text = @"http://www.grandlodgeofvirginia.org/lodges/48/";
          statedc.text = @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48 holds it's stated communication on the              
                           2nd Monday of the month at 7:30 PM. If there are
                            any exceptions to the regular meeting day or time, 
                            they are posted on the Lodge website.";

         lodgehistory.text = @"According to the earliest records the Abingdon Lodge had 
              its origin “At a meeting held at the house of
              James White in the town of Abingdon, on October 3, 1796.” The record
              states that a dispensation had been given by the Grand Master of
              Masons in Virginia and the following were present: William King,
              Master; Daniel Murphy, Past Master; Robert Johnson, Past Master;
              Charles Carson, Past Master, and William Preston Skillern. For more
              information on the Lodge History please see the Lodge website.";

         break;
```

Comment: Zaheer Ahmed, do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Which method contains that `switch` statement?

Comment: (lodgeNumber)....the tableview holds the names of lodges, the detailed view holds the LodgeNumber which holds the information that is not updating after a user preforms a search. The switch method is (lodgeNumber) However the self.title AKA lodgeName is updating correctly. Im unsure why the other data is not. After the sure is preformed the detailed data shows only case 0 and not the other cases.

Comment: `lodgeNumber` is a number, not a method.  (Look up the Objective-C definition of the word "method".)

Comment: Hi Phillip, (I'm new, guessing you figured that out by now). Thanks for the feed back. I guess Im really not understanding how this is going to help me. The switch is titled LodgeName which holds the key information Im trying to pass to the DVC after the search is completed. It works before the search is preformed but not after. Thanks again. An Ill look up method right now.

Comment: Im guessing I need a method to preform this? but Im not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MOVDetailViewController *MDVC = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSString * thelodge = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];

MDVC.lodgeName = thelodge;
MDVC = [segue destinationViewController];  // REMOVE THIS LINE
MDVC.lodgeNumber = path.row;
```